# Power of "number" accumulating in an Array

Tags: c

I got a formula in a program that depends on accumulating the power of a number inside an array. I registered this on other pages, but its not what I need :

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <math.h>
   int main (){
   int x, y, powernumber;
   scanf ("%d %d",&x,&y);
   powernumber = pow(x,y);
   printf ("Powernumber = %d",powernumber);
   return 0;}
```

its ok, but I have to assign a slot for each powernumber.

The issue at hand is this:

```
   int array [100];
   int i, int1;

   scanf ("%d",&int1);
   for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
   {array [i] = 1 / pow(2, int1); // <-----------------ERROR
   printf ("%d %d\n",i+1,array [i]);}
   return 0;}
```

The point of the formula, is that the user types in a number, and this number is to be accumulated as a powernumber, each time the loop makes a round, until the loop is terminated at i=100. lets say the user enters the number 3. the first time the program performs 2^3, then the next time 2^4, and then 2^5, in an array. It works with the ordinary operators like Multiplication and Division, but not the Power number. The example above is a stripped version, so it might work on a compiler. but hopefully the question is understandable .

Comment: When there is an error, do type the error message also to facilitate stack-overflowers understand the problem quickly.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error at least, `i<=100` should be `i < 100`. Now your loop tries to assign to `array[100]` on last iteration, which is an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

to get power numbers you need to do:

```
array [i] = (pow(2, int1));
```

to use division you need to use a float array and float representation for numbers. Also need to print as %f and not %d:

```
float array [100];
int i;
float int1;
scanf ("%d",&int1);
for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
{
    array [i] = 1.0 / pow(2.0, int1);
    printf ("%d %f\n",i+1,array [i]);
}
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way here : [Change int array to float array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560790/change-int-array-to-float-array-in-c)

and the version of the routine I will print here as gratitude .

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <math.h>
   //1D_Array(float). Create array, then divide 2 numbers and display sum.
   //KHO2016.no3. mingw (TDM-GCC-32) . c-ansi .
   int main()
   {
   //Declare
   int i,int1;
   float flp1,flp2,flp3,array[30];

   //valuate
   printf ("The program request 4 numbers\n");
   printf ("1. Number of Rows or loops\n2. Value above the fraction line\n");
   printf ("3. Value beneath the fraction line\n4. Value of Powernumber\n\n");

   jump :
   printf ("Type in number of loops, 1-30 :");
   scanf ("%d",&int1);
   if (int1>31)
   {printf ("Number is too large\n");
   goto jump;}

   else if (int1<=30)
   printf ("Type the number Above the Fraction line (Dividend) ");
   scanf ("%f",&flp1);
   printf ("Type the number beneath the Fraction line (Divisor) ");
   scanf ("%f",&flp2);
   printf ("Value of Powernumber ");
   scanf ("%f",&flp3);

   //calculate
   for (i<0;i<=int1-1;i++)
   {array[i]=(float)(flp1/pow(flp2, (++flp3)-1)); // <------ interesting part !
   printf ("Row [%d]\t%.0f / %.0f^%.0f = %.6f\n",i+1,flp1,flp2,flp3-1,(float)array[i]);}

   //terminate
   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. for starters it helped to do this

```
   for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
   {array [i] = 1 / (pow(2, int1++));
```

And I think I got it sorted. what I now have of a problem is to get Floating numbers in the Array. The array does what is expected. However here :

```
   float int1;
   printf ("%d %f\n",i+1,array [i]);
   // The array refuse to be display floating numbers.
   //If the array is defined as a Float it also refuses.
```

Comment: well it's an array of integers so you can't print a float and expect it to be correct

Comment: I agree ! But I think what made my fumble was that I divide the powernumber on 1. making the output numbers decimals. Now I have to find out how to make a floating number array. the question should have been concerning floating numbers in arrays instead. well.